# -Wmissing-include-dirs & automatically included header directories

Tags: xcode, directory, header

When building a project in Xcode (3.1.2), 2 folders are automatically added as header directories with the '-I' option:

```
/ (ProjPath) / (ProjName) / build / (BuildConfigName) / include  
/ (ProjPath) / (ProjName) / build / (ProjName).build / (BuildConfigName) / (ProjName).build / DerivedSources
```

I realized this when trying to add `-Wmissing-include-dirs` to the warnings list in my project.
A warning is emitted for both folders. This happens for both Cocoa Applications and C++ Dynamic Libraries. I haven't tried any other project type, but I suppose this behavior applies to any project type.

1. How are these folders used by Xcode?
2. Can they be either avoided, or automatically created by Xcode when build begins?
3. If not, how to successfully use `-Wmissing-include-dirs` with Xcode?

Thanks.

Comment: Those directories are used when you have derived sources that create header files or when part of your build generates header files (like building a dynamic library that is a separate target whose include files are then used by another target in the project. These cases are not used often and in an environment like Xcode, the -Wmissing-include-dirs warning is almost meaningless. I suggest you remove that warning and not attempt to change your project templates unless you know what you're doing and why :) You can also create them automatically by adding a run script build phase to your target.

Comment: My goal is to enable the warning IF it can be useful. Can you explain why it is almost meaningless in Xcode?

Comment: Because Xcode manages the build environment for you. That warning lets you know that you may have mistyped the path to some special include directory or that header files aren't installed in the expected places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a script to your target which creates the directories for your:

Right-click your target, select Add -> New Build Phase -> New Run Script Build Phase.
Drag this build phase to the top of your target, before the "Compile Sources" phase.

Then enter a script like this (by double-clicking the phase):

```
mkdir -p "${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/include"
mkdir -p "${PROJECT_DERIVED_FILE_DIR}"
```

You can see the various environment variables in the build transcript (Command-Shift-B, click the little text icon, drag the build transcript up.)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. PROJECT_DERIVED_FILE_DIR is not the variable needed in my case though (it does not include the Build Configuration name). DERIVED_FILES_DIR, DERIVED_FILE_DIR or DERIVED_SOURCES_DIR should be used instead.